# How to safe-move package intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package, intellij-14

I have my current project structure like this.

```
|--daos
|  |
|  |--readers
```

And I want to move whole readers packages like this.

```
|--daos
|  
|--dbs
   |
   |--readers
```

How can I do this safely without breaking usages using intellij?

Comment: Intellij will automatically change all class package . even you can do drag and drop also ..

Comment: Did you try drag and drop in the Project structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the package and choose Refactor, then move your package from there. It will confirm what you want to do, and make the necessary changes for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should just mark `readers` package in Project structure and press `Shift + F6`. Type `dbs.readers` and click `Refactor`. Make sure that `Search for references` is checked so it will safely refactor it everywhere in code.

If you want to add more layers just add `.` and type name that you want.